# How to unbind from all channels / events on pusher

Tags: pusher

In the javascript pusher client, is it possible to unbind all callbacks from a particular channel or event ?

Answer (score 0):

Channel inherit from [EventDispatcher](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/blob/master/src/events_dispatcher.js) and it doesn't presently offer an unbind all. You could hack it by re-initialising the `callbacks` member variable that manages the events on `channel`:

```
var pusher = new Pusher( '22364f2f790269bec0a0' );
var channel = pusher.subscribe( 'test-channel' );

var callback = function() {};

for( var i = 0, l = 10; i < l; ++i ) {
  channel.bind( 'event-' + i, callback );
}

console.log( channel.callbacks._callbacks );

channel.callbacks = new channel.callbacks.constructor();
```

You can see this in action [here](http://jsbin.com/UGaXafu/1/edit). **But this would be a hack**.

The best thing to do would be to submit a pull request to add an `unbind_all` function to the `EventDispatcher` object.